# Find words in a word grid

Tags: python, performance

I made a program to find words in a word grid. It will find words that are horizontal, vertical, positive sloped and vertical sloped, all in both forwards and backwards.

Here is my code:

```
with open('grid.txt', 'r') as f:
    lst = [[a for a in l.strip() if a != ' ' and a!= '\n'] for l in f.readlines() if l] # Convert file to a nested list, with all whitespaces removed
    lst2 = [a[::-1] for a in zip(*lst)] # Create another nested list that is the first nested list rotated 90 degrees clockwise
    
height = len(lst) # Height of grid
width = len(lst[0]) # Width of grid

while True:
    
    word = input("Input your word: ") # Word to find

    # Find horizontal word
    for l in lst:
        w = ''.join(l)
        if word in w or word in w[::-1]:
            print(w)
            print('Horizontal!')

    # Find vertical word
    for l in lst2:
        w = ''.join(l)
        if word in w or word in w[::-1]:
            print(w)
            print('Vertical!')

    # Find Negative slope
    for i in range(width):
        w = ''
        for j in range(height):
            try:
                w += lst[j][i]
                i += 1
            except:
                break
        if word in w or word in w[::-1]:
            print(w)
            print('Negative Slope!')

    for i in range(height):
        w = ''
        for j in range(width):
            try:
                w += lst[i][j]
                i += 1
            except:
                break
        if word in w or word in w[::-1]:
            print(w)
            print('Negative Slope!')

    # Find positive slope
    for i in range(height):
        w = ''
        for j in range(width):
            try:
                w += lst2[j][i]
                i += 1
            except:
                break
        if word in w or word in w[::-1]:
            print(w)
            print('Positive Slope!')
        
    for i in range(width):
        w = ''
        for j in range(height):
            try:
                w += lst2[i][j]
                i += 1
            except:
                break
        if word in w or word in w[::-1]:
            print(w)
            print('Positive Slope!')
```

Here is my `grid.txt`:

```
n x b z t a ê s e y m t w u e r r
y s j q l n o i l f k j c y h t a
q x n e z d l g v r x y x a p u a
b b k à a y e g q i h u x b q e u
m h z x r é q m x m e l t i b t q
i k i g c j c h w l w i ï t p u o
i s o w u w m a p z a b w g d e p
i p s g u y n n j i j f o f n w l
l i u l ô i e j b e o t s e b c j
y m f v f e v h f c p r d m y v n
f w h v d t z y i x t e e u v n e
e w x e h l x n q m s n p z e f b
e j l v r x ç t d b i a z v d h z
c i i n s s i b s t o q o d d k x
z o f c a w b j b l m w k f e i s
```

I feel like my code is unnecessarily long for a rather simple task.

Are there any ways to shorten and improve it?

Comment: Seems not to work. If I enter `zxs` from the lower-right, it does not output anything.

Comment: It's because of encoding. After copying and pasting your example file, I had to specify UTF-8 for your `open` call to get this thing to work.

Comment: The central slopes are printed twice, for example `nsn` from the top-left or `zil` from the bottom-left.

Comment: Re. your most recent edit to describe `strip()` - technically this is an example of _answer invalidation_, because the feedback I gave is now partially incorrect given your new constraints. This is something that CodeReview tries to avoid, and as such - if we were to be strict - your most recent edit should be rolled back. Please keep this in mind for future questions: once you have answers, you generally shouldn't edit your question at least in substance.

Comment: @Reinderien Oh! I'm very sorry! I'll roll it back.

Comment: @user229550 Consider accepting any answer :)\

Comment: @AryanParekh I will as soon as I find one more way that improves my code and does not make it longer.

Comment: @user229550 I linked a site which implements a much shorter and faster way,  you might want to check that out, or do you want me to add that in my review?

Comment: @user229550 Are you only looking to copy-paste the new code? It's better if you try to understand and implement it, also don't assume that shorter code is always better.

Comment: @AryanParekh I am not looking to copy-paste the new code. If so I could easily google "python word grid code". Note that I said "find one more way that *improves my code* and does not make it longer". I am fully aware that "shorter code is *not* always better". Your `.split()` was a nice tip for me.

Comment: @user229550 This is a little controversial, you might feel like you are copying if you follow the link I cited, but please don't think so. If you fully understand the method then it's absolutely fine. If you think that way then learning from any source can be considered as copying :), so try to understand that method as it's much cleaner and shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Catch invalid input

When I was trying out your code, I entered `Cntrl + Z` which crashed the program. Using [Try and Except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp#:%7E:text=The%20try%20block%20lets%20you,the%20try%2D%20and%20except%20blocks.) can prevent this from happening

```py
try:
    word = input("Enter your word:")
except Exception:
    print("Invalid input!")
```

- Also, I'd keep a check of `len(word) == 0` since an empty input is dangerous too

---

## Reading `grid.txt`

```py
with open('grid.txt', 'r') as f:
    lst = [[a for a in l.strip() if a != ' ' and a!= '\n'] for l in f.readlines() if l] 
    lst2 = [a[::-1] for a in zip(*lst)]
```

You can greatly simplify this part by using `list.split()`

```py
with open('grid.txt', 'r') as f:
    lst = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
    lst2 = list( zip (*lst[::-1]) )
```

If you're worried about the `'\n'` at the end, the new lists using this method will not have it.

- I'd suggest you keep the names of the lists as `horizontal` and `vertical` rather than `lst` and `lst2` which don't mean much

## Split work into functions

You should separate tasks into functions so that there isn't one huge block of code that does everything. Moreover, splitting work into functions makes it easy to maintain your code. What if your main game loop could look like this

```py
def game_loop():
    while True:
        word = take_input()
        matches = find_matches(grid,word)

        if matches == None: print("No matches")
        else:
            for match in matches:
                print( "Match: " + match )

        if input("Do you want to play again? (y/n): ").lower() == 'n':
            break
```

## An alternate approach

The reason your code isn't as efficient as the method I will just show you is that you repeatedly reverse the lists and use a lot of loops. There is a much better and cleaner way in which you need to go through the whole grid only once.

- Read the `.txt` file into a list ( like we previously did for `lst`)
- Start by going through each element in the 2-D list
- If the element matches the first character of the entered word, check all 8 directions to complete the match

[**Implementaion**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-a-word-in-a-2d-grid-of-characters/)

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things you need to avoid:

- `strip()` when you really just need `rstrip()`
- Forcing a caller of your program to loop through input; you should have functions to make this more divisible
- Keeping a list of lists of characters. Just keep lists of strings.
- Reversing the word on the inside of every loop; this should only be done once
- Iterating blindly over a sequence until you hit `IndexError`
- `except:` (you should catch the specific exception)

The following suggested implementation fixes your coordinate iteration so that you don't have to rely on exceptions.

```
def make_rot45(grid):
    m, n = len(grid[0]), len(grid)
    coords = (
        (
            (y + x, x) for x in range(max(0, -y), min(m, n-y))
        ) for y in range(1-m, n)
    )
    return [
        ''.join(grid[y][x] for y, x in coord_line)
        for coord_line in coords
    ]


def simple(word: str):
    with open('grid.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        rot0 = tuple(
            line.replace(' ', '').rstrip('\n')
            for line in f
        )

    rot90 = tuple(''.join(col[::-1]) for col in zip(*rot0))
    rot45 = make_rot45(rot0)
    rot135 = make_rot45(rot90)
    word_rev = word[::-1]

    for grid, message in (
        (rot0, 'Horizontal!'),
        (rot90, 'Vertical!'),
        (rot45, 'Negative Slope!'),
        (rot135, 'Positive Slope!'),
    ):
        try:
            line = next(line for line in grid if word in line or word_rev in line)
            print(line)
            print(message)
        except StopIteration:
            pass


for test_word in (
    'def',
    'ehk',
    'gko',
    'sqo',
):
    print(f'Test word "{test_word}":')
    simple(test_word)
    print()
```

I ran this against the following file:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
m n o
p q r
s t u
```

and it produced correct results.

Comment: Good points,+1, I missed them in my review. I wanted to clarify, is there any problem is using `list.split()` for reading the grid from the file?

Comment: Yes, there's at least two issues: it's not `list.split()`, but `line.split()`; and you shouldn't `split()` at all - simply `replace`. There's no need for an intermediate list representation.

Comment: But doesn't `.replace()` return a string, compared to OP's implementation which uses a `2x2` list?

Comment: It's not a 2x2 list; it's a two-deep nested list. And yes, it's different from the OP's implementation intentionally. There's no sense in storing lists of lists of characters if all you're doing is string membership tests.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason, when I remove the `try` `except` part of your code, I get an IndexError.

Comment: Keep in mind that `original_ish` is basically your code, with a few modifications; and certainly won't work if you remove the exception handling. The alternate implementation in `simple`/`make_rot45` does not need to produce and catch `IndexError`s to function; that's what I was getting at.